# Python Boto3 S3 : List only current directory file ignoring subdirectory files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to download file(s) from prefix folder and not its sub-directories inside prefix folder. I am running below but it list all file(s) inside prefix folder including sub-directories. Is there I can list only file(s) from prefix folder only ?

```
bucket = aws_resource_session.Bucket(bucket_name)
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3_end_point_properties["prefix"]):
    print(obj.key)
```

Thanks,
Imran Khan

Comment: if obj.get()['ContentType'] == 'application/x-directory':

Answer (score 10):

Rather than use the higher-level Resource interface [Bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket), which will simply give you a list of all objects within the bucket, you can use the lower-level [Client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client) interface. Specifically, if you include the Delimiter parameter when calling [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) then the results will return the objects at the given prefix in "Contents" and the 'sub-folders' in "CommonPrefixes".

Example:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

rsp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket="mybucket", Prefix="myprefix/", Delimiter="/")

print("Objects:", list(obj["Key"] for obj in rsp["Contents"]))
print("Sub-folders:", list(obj["Prefix"] for obj in rsp["CommonPrefixes"]))
```

Sample output with `Prefix="csv/"`:

```
Objects: ['csv/a.csv', 'csv/b.csv', 'csv/c.csv']
Sub-folders: ['csv/corrupt/', 'csv/complete/']
```

If you do not include the `Delimiter` parameter, then all objects at this prefix and below will be present in the `"Contents"`, for example:

```
Objects: ['csv/a.csv', 'csv/b.csv', 'csv/c.csv', 'csv/corrupt/d.csv', 'csv/complete/e.csv']
```

Comment: In my experiment, the output is: `Objects: ['csv/', 'csv/a.csv', 'csv/b.csv', 'csv/c.csv']` for the first sample code. Wondering how can I get rid of the directory name because I only want to list the files in a directory, not the directory itself.

Comment: @Zhiwei If `csv/` appears in Contents then it's because someone or some process explicitly created an object named `csv/`. Typically this happens when someone uses the AWS S3 Console and creates a folder named `csv`. You'll have to filter it out of the results yourself, which should be simple to do (just filter out strings ending in `/`). For example: `[f for f in objects if not f.endswith('/')]`

Comment: looks like this doesnt list 'folders' e.g. csv/corrupt will not be listed...too bad because can't be used for browsing single level objects

Comment: @magor not quite sure what you mean. The list_objects_v2 call can be used to list *all* objects, all folder objects (those 'folders' actually present as objects), and all virtual folders (those not actually present as objects but inferred from objects with a given prefix).

Comment: i meant, we need to use 2 calls to list objects in a level to include 'subfolders', rsp['Contents'] and rsp['CommonPrefixes']

Answer (score 2):

There is no "folder" in s3. Imagine everything in a single "folder" in the root. File Names are long and have "/" in them, that's how all the objects are stored. AWS is just being helpful as people are usually familiar with folder structure.

When you specify a prefix, you will get every object that starts with that.
You can use python's standard library for string manipulation to eke out what you don't want before the download.

You know that each object will have your prefix, so you can devise a way to strip prefix from each key first, then check to see if you still have '/' in the file name (i.e. s3 key). If there is, then that is "inside" the folder or a subfolder (I am using the terms you used to make it clear), which you dont want.

E.g.:

```
objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix)
[obj for obj in objects if '/' not in obj.key.replace(prefix,'')]
```